# Trying to make a BLE app with Ionic and Angular using the cordova plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins

I am struggling installing everything properly. It seems that cordova and Ionic are not compatible anymore? I don't know.

I am following along with the docs from ionic, and the github they link there https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central .
Installing the cordova BLE plugin using the command line `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central` lets the program recognize the BLE import from here
`import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble/ngx';`, but then the app stops building anything. I just get a blank screen.

Can someone walk me through setting up an ionic/angular project and adding the cordova plugin for BLE. I think I understand how to use the plugin, the docs are pretty thorough there, but the installing part is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this plugin instead. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-le.
I've been using that plugin for a few years on ionic v3.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that one a try! As soon as I can get Ionic to build on my device. I've been struggling with Cordova/gradle/daemon for a while now. You wouldn't happen to know of a good guide to setting up an ionic app on a device? Something other than Ionic's because theirs doesn't give much direction with installing Java/cordova/etc... which I don't have

Comment: I can't remember the exact steps when I was starting up. But I just followed some online guide and most of it are from the ionic docs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but I've just discovered this question while working with the `cordova-plugin-ble-central` plugin myself.

1. Make sure all packages are installed
2. Import the plugin as a provider in the `app.module.ts`
3. Import the plugin in the page/component that you are using it

Be sure you also install the npm package `@ionic-native/ble` as is mentioned in the documentation. I have found that some errors then occur due to the missing `@ionic-native/core` package.
Both of those can be installed using `npm`.

```
npm install @ionic-native/ble @ionic-native/core
```

As a next step make sure you import the plugin that you want to use it in, but also in your `app.module.ts`.
Then add `BLE` to the providers in the `@NgModule` declaration.
As an example:

```js
// other imports...
import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    BLE, // add BLE here
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```